# Get rid of "Rendering Problems" dialog in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

How to permanently get rid of this dialog in Android Studio's layout preview? I am tired of closing it again and again, as it pops up again when I make changes in my layout.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/T9eScuk.png]

Comment: have u used any custom library?

Comment: android studio cant render that custom widget then... it can only render those widgets that are defined in its platform tools.... dont mind this error.. just close it and you will still get the widget highlighted as per your cursor in the xml

Comment: @HirakChhatbar Well this error dialog is not letting me see the layout. Everytime I make changes in my layout, the dialog pops up :S

Comment: close the dialog again... i dont thi this dialog restricts changes to the layout... refresh manually to see updated layout....

Comment: @HirakChhatbar It does not restrict any xml changes. It restricts the viewing of rendered view. See the screenshot. It covering the preview and I am unable to see.

Comment: thats what i want to convey.. may be my bad.. but there is not way android can render the custom widgets.. in case the custom library has provided its own stuff to render its widgets.....

Comment: @HirakChhatbar Can't I just hide the warnings permanently in IDE?

Comment: you could check the `isInEditMode()` flag on the onDraw() of your custom view.

Comment: @Blackbelt I am using gradle dependency of the library, so I cannot modify its source :(

Comment: well, I guess you could extend that class, and returning without calling the super class if you are in edit mode. Not a big deal

Comment: Rendering problem occurs when designer preview using higher API version than your version